# How to handle click event in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I know this question has been asked a 100 times, but I couldn't find any answers related to my issue because I'm new and their code is completely different. I'm displaying images from `Firebase` into `RecyclerView` when the images clicked it must open the image like a pop-up or in an `Activity`.

> quote.java

```
public class quote extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Post List");
    int noc =2;
    mRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,noc));

    mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(Model.class,R.layout.row,ViewHolder.class,mRef) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {

                    viewHolder.setDetails(model.getTitle(), model.getImage());
                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(quote.this,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
 }
}
```

> Model.java

```
public class Model {

  String title,image;

  public Model(){}

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getImage() {
    return image;
  }

  public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
  }

}
```

> ViewHolder.java

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  View mView;

  public ViewHolder( View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
  }

  public void setDetails(String title, String image){
    TextView mTitleTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
    ImageView mImageTv = mView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);

    mTitleTv.setText(title);
    Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageTv);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to implement click on `ImageView` or on `RecyclerView Item`?

Comment: @Yupi Sorry I couldn't get you i'm displaying image and text in recycle view, when the user clicks that it must open to view image a little bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mImageTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Do open image zoom activity
                            }
                        });
```

you can use [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library as an activity to zoom your ImageView. 
for smooth transition use [this](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50) guide for transition animation

Answer (score 2):

You need to use itemView.

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(quote.this,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
});
```

Comment: How to implement that? Any useful links would be great!

Comment: does it working? you want to implement the click on image or item?

Comment: Sorry I could differentiate between them, click on the image I think so. Because the user needs to see the image in full view. @Zuhrain

Answer (score 2):

```
  ViewHolder.ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemListener.recyclerViewListClicked(view, position);
            }
        });
```

Send Interface context or callback to Adapter Constructor from your Fragment or Activity While Setting/Calling Adapter and OnBindviewHolder Set Data to Interface function and implements those function in Activity or Fragment to access data on Click

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see image enlarged, dismiss on swipe down/up you can use supporting libraries like *Fresco* from *Facebook* here is the implementation guide: 
https://frescolib.org/docs/index.html or you could use some *Fresco* wrappers which make easier to use *Fresco* for example: https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer

So by using *Fresco* you could do like this, image will appear in full screen or customised size:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse("image url here");
      draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
   }
});
```

Comment: I have over 100+ images is it feasible.

Comment: Every image is opened like single image and than you are able to make it swipe left and right to move on next image basically *Facebooks* preview of images.